# ¿Es correcto decir "salir afuera"?

Tags: vocabulario, gramática

Asumiendo que se está en un edificio con muchas oficinas, ¿es correcto decir
"salí afuera de la oficina"? Porque si se dice "salí de la oficina" no se sabe si la persona esta dentro del edificio pero fuera de la oficina. ¿O cuál es la manera correcta de decirlo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me add something else.

This is called pleonasm. Pleonasm is not necessarily wrong. According to the DUE (Diccionario de Uso del Espanhol):

"... puede añadir gracia o expresividad a la frase, otras veces constituye verdadera redundancia, y, en ocasiones, aunque podría tacharse de tal, es una manera de dar una terminación a la frase que, de otro modo, quedaría como incompleta."

So... The key is to realize you're doing it, because it must be done with good taste. It must only be used to give the expression vigor and grace. Acceptable examples:  “Yo lo vi con mis ojos”, “Lo escribí de puño y letra”, "volvio a reincidir".

In your case "sali afuera de la oficina" seems perfectly reasonable, in my opinion. Had it been said "sali de la oficina" that would be a tad imprecise/incomplete and "salí de la oficina, pero no del edificio" sounds a bit bombastic.

Comment: oh thanks a lot for making this clear :) so its ok to do so whenever you want to make emphasis. Ill try to accept the answer as soon as it lets me o_o

Answer (score 5):

En principio esto no es correcto.

A esto se le llama un [pleonasmo](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasmo) y, según mis cursos de secundaria (High School) esto es un "vicio del lenguaje".

En el contexto muy particular que mencionas es mejor complementar la frase con una aclaración, aglo así como:

> Salí de la oficina, pero no del edificio.

Comment: I read the wikipedia artilce however I can still not find in any plance (or wikipedia) that it something that it's wrong and shouldn't be used/done. If you have some article regarding this I would appreciate it.

Comment: @Raykud: this link http://maestrosonline1.blogspot.ca/2009/06/vicios-del-lenguaje.html is quite long but if you look for the term "pleonasmo" you will see that it can be the useless repetition of a concept with synonyms. It does have some uses in literature and other contexts, even every day conversation, but it really depends on the context. Your example is one in which it should not be used.

Comment: So, its right to use it in some context but not right in others? that sounds confusing. I will accept the answer however I will look forward for something that would clarify when its right to use it. Thanks tho.

Comment: -1 El pleonasmo no es un vicio del lenguaje, ni algo incorrecto. Es un recurso que se puede utilizar correctamente, como muchos otros. La respuesta de @carlosdc lo explica bien.